# What is hermes engine (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

How hermes can be faster and does it affect on IOS or no it just make faster android app?

Comment: https://code.fb.com/android/hermes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply different interpreter for android, its not affect IOS.

But anyway if you want have reduced size of app on android maybe bundle instead of apk will be good fit for you :)